# Where to put code in Model View or Controller to manage User priviliges and url manipulation protection in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, security

Apologies if this has been asked before, I've done a search and haven't found anything specific.  This is has been helpful http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Auzigog/2008/12/29/where-should-my-code-go

I'm trying to fix some code I inherited and I found you can change anyone's password, just change the URL:

/site/user/changepassword/(insert id)

I then placed in the user controller, pardon my pseudocode:

```
if(session.user_id == id_from_link)
   view changepasswordform(id_from_link)
else
   warn_and_redirect();
```

I think that was the right thing to do and in the right place?

Now in the Views I find code like this:

```
if(user_type is admin)
 echo admin options
if(user_type is user)
 echo user options
```

Now shouldn't that ideally be the View just having:

```
echo options
```

and then the Controller has:

```
switch(user_type)
  case: admin
     options = admin stuff
  case: user
     options = user stuff
```

and so on? or should this be in the User Model?

Comment: Should the View have any logic in it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the id parameter from the url... and at the top of the controller action add this:

```
function changepassword(){
   $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
   ....
}
```

Now the password will only be changed on the current user that is logged in. Be sure to do your normal checks of making sure $id is not null.

Comment: Thanks! I have found that "My Details" and "View Users" pages also suffer from the same URL manipulation!

Comment: Also be sure to check that the ID cannot be overridden. The ID should not be included in the Form or if it is, be changed to the current user's ID before saving. Otherwise the current user would be able to modify the value in the form and update another users password ;)

Answer (score 0):

View should effectively be print statements:

```
<title><?=$this->data['title']?></title>
...
<h1><?=$this->data['main_menu']?></h1>
```

Controller should prep the view/handle the request:

```
if(loggedInUser) {
    $this->data['title'] = model->getTitle(userID);
    $this->redirect(/somepage);
}
else {
    $this->redirect(/loginpage);
}
```

Model should have:

```
function getTitle($userID) {
   this->doStuff($userID);
   $title = this->talkToDB($userID);
   return $title;
}
```